# I want to insert a value from an array into a column of sql table, but the content is not going into the table?

Tags: php, sql

```
for($i=0;$i<=feof($getdata);$i++)
{
if (filter_var($data[$i][1], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
echo $data[$i][1];
$email=$data[$i][1];
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql ="INSERT INTO promo_user (uid,name,email) VALUES (,'', '$email')";
mysqli_query($sql,$conn);
mysqli_close($conn);
```

i am using the above code but there is something wrong with it,whenever i run the code the echo is working fine but the content does go into sql table

Please help

Comment: why are you creating a connection inside a loop?

Comment: your `insert` `$sql ="INSERT INTO promo_user (uid,name,email) VALUES (,'', '$email')";` you are only inserting two values.

Comment: if the uid is an auto_increment leave it out of the query

Comment: remove 'uid' from query

Comment: `mysqli_query($conn,$sql);` . the first parameter should be `$conn` and last parameter `$sql`

Comment: values start with `,` ?

Comment: you would have caught all these errors had you added `error_reporting(E_ALL)`

Comment: See [How to get mysqli error in different environments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-in-different-environments)

Answer (score 1):

You have the arguments transposed - the correct order is

```
mysqli_query($con,$query)
```

So the first parameter of `mysqli_query` will be the connection and second is query.

Also, you can make connection outside the loop, so connection will be initiated only one time.